# Are the following two situations equivalent?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Below are the two different situations in which the rope wraps twice around the top of the top pulley and bottom of the bottom pulley(Assume that the segment of the rope attached to the center of top pulley is essentially vertical).

[image]

I'm confused whether the two situations are same or not?

Comment: What happens if the tension in the rope is equal to the weight of the man?

Comment: @R.Emery Block will move

Comment: The rope held by the man

Comment: In first case block will move but I'm not sure about second case

Comment: How much weight is being suspended?

Comment: $M+m$ weight is being suspended in both cases by rope. My confusion is effect due to additional rope(that man is holding) in second case.

Comment: Think harder. I have already told you what you need to know

Comment: I think both are same as man is holding same weight

Comment: $M$ is the weight of the block and $m$ is the weight of the man. So how come they are equal? I guess that first image of yours is wrong one (since it has the weight of the block = $M+m$) If it isn't, you'll have to take some other term for the man's weight.

Comment: I have edited the first image because I wanted to know if there is same effect of block of mass $M+m$ as in second case in which man of mass $m$ is standing holding the rope on a block of mass $M$

Comment: As far as I see they're both the same situations.

Comment: tension works in both directions

Comment: In first case tension holding the block is $4T$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify let's assume that the systems are in equilibrium. Then the equations for the systems become:

For (a):
\begin{align}
4T = (M+m)g \text{, } \hspace{1em} T = mg - N \tag 1 \\
\therefore \hspace{1em} T = \frac{M+m}{4}g \text{, } \hspace{1em} N = \frac{3m - M}{4}g \tag 2
\end{align}

For (b):
\begin{align}
4T = Mg + N \text{, } \hspace{1em} T = mg - N \tag 3 \\
\therefore \hspace{1em} T = \frac{M+m}{5}g \text{, } \hspace{1em} N = \frac{4m - M}{5}g \tag 4
\end{align}
where $T$ is the tension in the strings, $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity and $N$ is the normal force exerted by the contact surfaces.

Now in equation (3) for $M = 3m$ the normal force becomes zero, and the same in equation (4) is true for $M = 4m$, i.e. the situations are not the same.

Comment: For the original poster: N is the force of the mans feet upon the thing he is standing on.

Comment: yes, that is correct.